# anova type III test for a GLMM

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I am fitting a `glmer` model in the `lme4` R package. I'm looking for an anova table with p-value shown therein, but I cannot find any package that fits it. Is it possible to do it in R?

The model I am fitting is of the form:

```
model1<-glmer(dmn~period*teethTreated+(1|fullName), 
   family="poisson", 
   data=subset(dataset, 
          group=='Four times a year'),
   control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're willing to settle for Wald tests this should work:

```
library(lme4)
library(car)
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
                   data = cbpp, family = binomial)
Anova(gm1,type="III")
```

However, note (from `?Anova`) that:

> The designations "type-II" and "type-III" are borrowed from SAS,
>        but the definitions used here do not correspond precisely to those
>        employed by SAS.  Type-II tests are calculated according to the
>        principle of marginality, testing each term after all others,
>        except ignoring the term's higher-order relatives; so-called
>        type-III tests violate marginality, testing each term in the model
>        after all of the others. This definition of Type-II tests
>        corresponds to the tests produced by SAS for analysis-of-variance
>        models, where all of the predictors are factors, but not more
>        generally (i.e., when there are quantitative predictors).  Be very
>        careful in formulating the model for type-III tests, or the
>        hypotheses tested will not make sense.

I would check your results very carefully to make sure they make sense!

Alternatively, you can use `afex::mixed` to get analogous tables via likelihood ratio test or parametric bootstrap; the latter is the most accurate, but also the slowest by far.

See `?pvalues` in the `lme4` package for more general discussion of p-value computation in the context of GLMMs.