# whether the car::Anova function can be used for GLMM

Tags: anova, glmm, car

Now, I am running a generalized linear mixed model using lme4 package.  I have three category factors (factor 1 has three levels, factor 2 has two levels, factor 3 has five levels).  And I want to have the main and interaction effects of them.  Here is the model I built:

```
Model <- glmer(family=binomial, data=data1, 
               formula=value~factor1*factor2*factor3+(1|item)+(1|subject), 
               control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e7)))
    summary(Model)
    car::Anova(Model)
```

1. I wonder whether I can use `car::Anova(Model)` to get the main and interaction effects? Is this function suitable for generalized linear mixed model?
2. And if I have the three-way interaction, how could I do next? Do the post hoc? Or separate one factors to see the influence on the other interactions?

Comment: The first question is probably answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101566/anova-type-iii-test-for-a-glmm). As for the second, if you decided to go with a multiple comparisons test (post hoc), the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013260/post-hoc-test-for-glmer?rq=1) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/how-to-perform-post-hoc-test-on-lmer-model). I usually prefer something along the lines of: library(emmeans) emmeans(Model, list(pairwise ~ factor1*factor2*factor3), adjust = "tukey") *Note: I have included this as an answer becaus