# Results of Type-3 Wald Chi-Square Different for GLMM with Different Contrast Coding

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts, categorical-encoding

I have just completed a multilevel, longitudinal logistic regression testing, at four different time points, whether participants in an experimental group are more likely to have committed any drug-related crime in the previous 4 weeks than participants receiving placebo.

The syntax for the glmer looks like this

```
sumDrug <- summary(drugMod <- glmer(drugCrime ~ group*week + (1|id), data = oti, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 10))
```

Where `drugCrime` is the binary outcome variable "have committed one or more drug-related crimes in previous 4 weeks?" (Y/N response), `group` is a factor indicating group allocation, and `week` is a factor indicating time of measurement (at weeks 0, 4, 8, and 12).

If I treatment code the two factors (see [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)) the output of the regression (with Odds Ratios and CIs) looks like this:

```
           var Estimate Std..Error z.value Pr...z..   OR   lo   hi
1  (Intercept)   -1.234      0.562  -2.197    0.028 0.29 0.04 2.28
2       group2   -0.108      0.779  -0.139    0.890 0.90 0.11 7.02
3        week2   -1.450      0.632  -2.295    0.022 0.23 0.03 1.84
4        week3   -0.965      0.652  -1.480    0.139 0.38 0.05 2.98
5        week4   -0.696      0.652  -1.067    0.286 0.50 0.06 3.90
6 group2:week2   -1.366      1.011  -1.351    0.177 0.26 0.03 2.00
7 group2:week3   -0.822      1.001  -0.821    0.411 0.44 0.06 3.44
8 group2:week4   -2.580      1.136  -2.271    0.023 0.08 0.01 0.59
```

And the output of the `Anova(drugMod)` in the `car` package returns

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: drugCrime
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
(Intercept) 4.8248  1    0.02805 *
group       0.0193  1    0.88955  
week        5.5199  3    0.13745  
group:week  5.4146  3    0.14383
```

If, on the other hand, I simple code the two factors (also see [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)) the output of the regression looks like this:

```
    var Estimate Std..Error z.value Pr...z..   OR   lo   hi 
1  (Intercept)   -2.661      0.499  -5.328    0.000 0.07 0.01
2       group1   -1.300      0.742  -1.752    0.080 0.27 0.03
3        week2   -2.133      0.548  -3.890    0.000 0.12 0.02
4        week3   -1.376      0.532  -2.584    0.010 0.25 0.03
5        week4   -1.986      0.600  -3.311    0.001 0.14 0.02
6 group1:week2   -1.366      1.011  -1.351    0.177 0.26 0.03
7 group1:week3   -0.822      1.001  -0.821    0.411 0.44 0.06
8 group1:week4   -2.580      1.136  -2.271    0.023 0.08 0.01
```

this time the output of the `Anova(drugMod)` is

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: drugCrime
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept) 28.3890  1  9.923e-08 ***
group        3.0684  1  0.0798276 .  
week        17.8728  3  0.0004672 ***
group:week   5.4149  3  0.1438151
```

I understand why the regression outputs are different with the two different contrast coding schemes, but why am I getting two different `Anova()` outputs for these two different coding schemes, and which is the 'correct' one to report? In a reply to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101566/anova-type-iii-test-for-a-glmm?rq=1) @Ben Bolker quotes the `Anova()` help, saying "Be very careful in formulating the model for type-III tests, or the hypotheses tested will not make sense." But I am not sure what 'makes sense' means in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be a little careful with `car:Anova(..., type=3)` since it only performs Type III tests if the sum-to-zero constrast coding (`contr.sum`) is used and if there are no "missing cells" or other estimability issues (to borrow a term from linear model theory).

The contrasts that `car:Anova(..., type=3)` produce is what I would call *marginal* contrasts and also what you get from `nlme::anova.lme(..., type="marginal")`. In "nice" cases these contrasts correspond to Type III contrasts if `contr.sum` is used.

My advice is therefore to:

1. Look at your data to check if there are any missing cells (use `table(group, week)`). Estimability issues often show up as `NA` in summary coefficient tables if you use `lm` but `glmer` may not display them. From the looks of your model summary you are *probably* ok.
2. Set the contrast-coding to `contr.sum`, fit the model, obtain the Type III tests:

   `options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
   drugMod <- glmer(drugCrime ~ group*week + (1|id), ....)
   car::Anova(drugMod, type=3)`
3. It is possible to obtain the Type III tests using contrasts of Least-Square Means (or in this case their GLM generalisation). Russell Lenth has added extensive guides to his **emmeans** package and [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) describes how to obtain the type III tests in this way. I would compare these with the results from `car::Anova`. Note that this approach will also not yield Type III if there are missing cells or estimability issues, but **emmeans** warns you if it detects such problems (and I think this is also implemented for `glmer` fits).

[This very recommendable vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/tests.pdf) has a very insightful discussion of Type III contrasts. It termed the approach in `car:Anova(..., type=3)` Not-Safe-Type-Three and it mentions that the instruction to use `contr.sum` is in the `car`-book (see footnote on page 15). It also has a description of which hypotheses are actually being tested if you use `contr.treatment` or `contr.SAS` and why these are probably not hypotheses that you are actually interested in (this addresses the "will not make sense" quote you mention).

#### Edit in order to answer: "what is 'missing cells' and how to detect them?"

As an example of a real data set with missing cells, consider the soup data
from the **ordinal** package. Note the 0-entry in the following tabulation:

```
data("soup", package="ordinal")
soup$RESPONSE <- as.numeric(as.character(soup$SURENESS))
with(soup, table(DAY, PRODID)) 
   PRODID
DAY   1   2   3   4   5   6
  1 369  94 184  93  88  93
  2 370 275   0  92  97  92
```

If we fit a model with the interaction between `PRODID` and `DAY`, one coefficient
is not estimable which shows up as `NA`:

```
fm <- lm(RESPONSE ~ DAY * PRODID, data=soup)
summary(fm)

Call:
lm(formula = RESPONSE ~ DAY * PRODID, data = soup)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2043 -1.4486  0.8043  1.3818  2.5514 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.94580    0.09421  41.883  < 2e-16 ***
DAY2         -0.49715    0.13314  -3.734 0.000194 ***
PRODID2       0.67122    0.20908   3.210 0.001349 ** 
PRODID3       1.11398    0.16332   6.821 1.23e-11 ***
PRODID4       0.59183    0.20998   2.819 0.004876 ** 
PRODID5       0.92920    0.21469   4.328 1.58e-05 ***
PRODID6       1.25850    0.20998   5.993 2.47e-09 ***
DAY2:PRODID2  0.49831    0.25392   1.962 0.049861 *  
DAY2:PRODID3       NA         NA      NA       NA    
DAY2:PRODID4  0.51386    0.29756   1.727 0.084347 .  
DAY2:PRODID5  0.62215    0.29784   2.089 0.036854 *  
DAY2:PRODID6  0.48850    0.29756   1.642 0.100823    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.81 on 1836 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1022,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.09735 
F-statistic: 20.91 on 10 and 1836 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

In general any source of non-estimability is a problem but **R** goes a long way
to eliminate such problems in the way design matrices are constructed.
I can think of two relevant sources of non-estimability: missing cells and
perfectly correlated covariates and most people already automatically avoid
the latter.

If there were no missing cells the Type III test of `DAY` would test the difference between days at an average `PRODID` (i.e., a simple, flat, unweighted average). This is exactly the Yates contrast that Therneau discusses, but in the presence of missing cells this straight-forward interpretation no longer holds. You might want to stay clear of Type III tests in such cases due to lack of interpretability...

Comment: Thank you @Rune H Christensen, a rich source or information and references. I will definitely look into emmeans. Can I ask what you mean by 'missing cells'; a few missing values here and there, or entire cells (e.g. Within a 2 X 4 design) with no values present?

Comment: I checked and when I simple-code the contrasts for `group` and `week` it yields the same results in the `Anova()` as if I use the global `options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))` command. I figured the `type=3` specification in `Anova()` would 'brute force' even a treatment-coded GLM into proper Type 3 sums of squares, but evidently not. Disconcerting but at least I know now. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: And thanks for the second vignette you mentioned. Terry Therneau is always an excellent read.

Comment: I updated the answer to address the "what is meant by 'missing cells'?" question.